# is there elegant way to get data from 3 options?

Tags: django

I need to get title from data or instance or None

actually there may not be any instance then None

something like this

```
title = data.get('title', None)
```

but also try to get from instance if possible

```
title = data.get('title', instance.title, None)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you want. Filter data?

Comment: @ShafikurRahmanShaon nope, just get title from request.data or from instance and then None

Answer (score 1):

You can try this
`x = getattr(data, 'title', None)`

The getattr() method takes multiple parameters:

- object - object whose named attribute's value is to be returned name
- string that contains the attribute's name default (Optional)
- value that is returned when the named attribute is not found